# Complex integration in a Banach space.

Tags: complex-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space, and $f:\mathbb{C}\to X$  a function from the complex plan $\mathbb{C}$ with values in $X$.
I am trying to give meaning to the integral
$$\int_C f(\lambda)\,d\lambda.$$
over a contour $C$.

If $X=\mathbb{C}$ we know that $$\int_C f(\lambda)\,d\lambda=\int_\alpha^\beta f(\phi(t))\phi'(t) \,dt.$$
Where $\phi(t)=x(t)+iy(t),\, \alpha\leq t \leq \beta$ is a parametric representation of the curve $C$.

Comment: There's a nice description in Rudin's functional analysis on vector valued integration.  It's in chapter 3

Comment: Still the same thing, $\int_Cf(\lambda)\,d\lambda:=\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}f(\phi(t))\phi'(t)\,dt$. The only thing is you now consider the function $F:[\alpha,\beta]\to X$, $F(t)=f(\phi(t))\phi'(t)$, so you need a notion of integration of functions defined on a measure space (here $[\alpha,\beta]$ with usual Lebesgue measure) taking values in a Banach space (Lang, Amann and Escher, Rudin all treat this sort of stuff; Folland gives a guided exercise for the basic definitions, and I'm sure there are several other references).

Comment: @peek-a-boo Are the results in the classical complex analysis still true for this generalisation, such as Cauchy-Riemann equations imply analytic, and Cauchy integral formula...

Comment: Yes, lot's of results extend almost verbatim. See the following answers of mine: [Generalizing the Analyticity of holomorphic functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4116765/568204), and [Reference request : Holomorphic functions with values in Banach spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4217882/568204), and here's some stuff about the [inverse/implicit function theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4151082/568204).

Comment: The unique thing that you need to make the integral well-defined is that $f$ is almost-separable valued. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral)